# Why sequence cannot be multiplied in clojure?

Tags: collections, clojure, range

Why the first statement is executed normally?

```
((fn [coll] (filter even? coll)) (range 10))
```

but the second one didn't.

```
((fn [coll] (* 2 coll)) (range 10))

Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/eval4361$fn (REPL:1).
class clojure.lang.LongRange cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (clojure.lang.LongRange is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Number is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

In C language, I can double the value in a for loop

```
int a=0
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  a = 2 * i;
}
```

If I want to double the value of range with an anonymous functions in clojure , what should I do? please feel free to comment.

Comment: that would be `((fn [coll] (map #(* % 2) coll)) (range 10))`

Answer (score 3):

That C code finishes with `a = 18` and doesn't create any range. If I understand correctly, you want this result:

```
'(0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18)
```

This can be achieved with [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map):

```
(map #(* % 2) (range 10))
```

Note that [`range`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range) has `step`, so you can also write:

```
(range 0 20 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the exception is that you are trying to multiply 2 with a range.  `(* 2 coll)` in this case evaluates to `(* 2 '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))`.  Hence the exception.

As others have pointed out, you likely wanted `(map #(* 2 %) coll)` instead of `(* 2 coll)`.

Some languages will notice that you are trying to apply a function to a collection and automatically do the `map` for you.  In Clojure, the `map` has to be explicit.

Comment: I didn't aware that "range 10" is NOT a for loop, I expect that the statement returns an element, but the statement returns a list elements. Finally, I solved the problem with "map" and "anonymous function".  (map (fn [n] (* 2 n)) (range 10)), thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Why the first statement is executed normally?
>
> ```
> ((fn [coll] (filter even? coll)) (range 10))
> ```

Let's break this apart to make it easier to understand:

```
(let [f (fn [coll]
          (filter even? coll))]
  (f (range 10)))
```

Now if we substitute `(range 10)` into `f` we get:

```
(filter even? (range 10))
```

`even?` is a predicate function and `(range 10)` produces a sequence, so `filter` is happy.

> but the second one didn't.
>
> ```
> ((fn [coll] (* 2 coll)) (range 10))
>
> Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/eval4361$fn (REPL:1).
> ```

This time, if we substitute `(range 10)` into the function, we get:

```
(* 2 (range 10))
```

The `*` function only accepts numbers as arguments.  `2` is a number, but `(range 10)` is a sequence of numbers.  A sequence of numbers is not a number, hence the exception.

In your C example, `a` is simply the last value calculated by the `for`-loop.  Here are a few ways you could express the same in clojure:

```
(last (map (partial * 2) (range 10)))

(last (map * (constantly 2) (range 10)))

(last (for [x (range 10)]
        (* 2 x)))
```